# Time series classification with handcrafted features

Tags: deep-learning, cnn, lstm

I have a dataset with handcrafted statistical features such as follows:

```
    UserID     AccelX_mean1   accelX_mean2   accelX_mean3  accelY_mean1  accelY_mean2 ....    target
```

Using sensor data such as accelerometer and gyroscope, statistical features have been created and they are window (3 days, where mean 1, mean 2 and mean 3 are day  1,2,3 accordingly). Every row is a different user.
I need to perform classification, which is binary, and the target can be either 1 or 0 for different users.
Are LSTM/GRU suitable for timeseries data that have windows and are of time series classification problem?
What would an appropriate simple architeture look like, if using recurent networks or are CNN more suitable?
I have read and seen implementations with time series predictions, but the data fed has usually been raw so I am unsure about a suitable method.

Any guidance is appreciated.
Thank you